# I want to fetch contents of a file.txt and print it only up to a certain keyword php

Tags: php, fopen

Let's consider that there is a text file called 1.txt which has the following content.

```
wow<br>wow<br>wow<!--Read More--><br>wow<br>wow<br>wow<br>wow<br>wow<br>wow<br>
```

I want to display its contents only upto the `<!--Read More-->`
Presently am using fopen command to read and display whole text file.

```
$file_handle = fopen("posts/1.txt", "r");
while (!feof($file_handle)) {
$line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
print $line_of_text;
}
```

Kindly someone help me with this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$file_handle = fopen("posts/1.txt", "r");
while ((!feof($file_handle) && (($line_of_text = fgets($file_handle)) != "<!--Read More-->")) 
{
  print $line_of_text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Warning**: This works only if your "stop text" is always on the same line

You can use [strstr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) function to check if the line you read contains the string on which to stop.

Calling it with your line as the first parameter, the string searched as the second and `true` as the third parameter will return `false` if the string searched is not in the line or it will return the part of the line **before** the string searched.

```
$file_handle = fopen("posts/1.txt", "r");
while (!feof($file_handle)) {
    /* Retrieve a line */
    $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
    /* Check if the stop text is in the line. If no returns false
       else return the part of the string before the stop text */
    $ret = strstr($line_of_text, "<!--Read More-->", true);
    /* If stop text not found, print the line else print only the beginning */
    if (false === $ret) {
        print $line_of_text;
    } else {
        print $ret;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works fine :) Thanks :) but my domain says that Warning: Wrong parameter count for strstr() in /home/karnaehg/public_html/postboard.php on line 36. How to correct this error?

Comment: @user2046614 : You must have an old version of PHP (before 5.3) so the third parameter of `strstr` does not exist in your version